# Invalid Column Name using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework to generate my model and whilst the generation of the model itself is successful I'm getting the following error when querying the database.

> Invalid column name 'EmployeeDealer_EmployeeDealerID'

The code that throws the exception is:

```
var employee = db.Employees.Where(emp => emp.EmployeeID == employeeId).FirstOrDefault();
```

It all looks fairly straightfoward so I'm assuming EF hasn't been able to generate the proper keys or ORM classes?

Here's the DB Schema for the related tables.

[image: DB Schema]

Any assistance on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the query that is being sent to the DB? What does your class look like? What do your Data Annotations or Fluent API mappings look like?

Comment: Good point - here's a [https://gist.github.com/serdar/c74cd441fb757d5a4bf00a2d183cd6f7] (Gist Link) of the generated query, it's generated a column that doesn't exist.

Comment: The classes that have been generated including the mapping classes are here [https://gist.github.com/serdar/26f61a9405458252adee18ddede9c5d7]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by changing the modified classes. Within the constructor in  the **Employee** class I removed the following statement:

```
this.Employees = new List<Employee>();
```

and also removed the following property

```
public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

Then again in the **EmployeeDealer** class I removed from the constructor:

```
this.Employees = new List<Employee>();
```

and also the property

```
public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

So I guess the issue lies in auto-generating an entity for a many-to-many table you need to ensure that the references (I'm assuming the navigation path) between the two other tables are produced correctly.